# What is DateTime.ToBinary vs. Ticks and FromBinary vs. constructor

Tags: c#, datetime

I noticed that `DateTime` has `ToBinary` and `Ticks`, which seem to return the same values. Furthermore `FromBinary` and the constructor that takes a long value both seem to result in the same object.

Why do both exist? Are there differences on other platforms or gotchas I should be aware of?

Comment: You could [read the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tobinary%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which answers  your question.

Comment: for anyone else - there can be a major difference. Per the reference source it seems to depend whether the Kind is  DateTimeKind.Local. In my case i had ToBinary() return -8586720986540643690 and Ticks return 636651086314132118.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[According to MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tobinary%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), `ToBinary` respects the `Kind` property as well. They explain it well in 2 sentences:

> Use the ToBinary method to convert the value of the current DateTime
>   object to a binary value. Subsequently, use the binary value and the
>   FromBinary method to recreate the original DateTime object.

You can [view the source for the implementation here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,c6309e27def6368e).